# How do I force compiler to generate error or warning when I forget to catch an exception

Tags: c++, exception

If forgot to catch exception, It will return to the runtime or handled by Exception Handler function defined.
or I can wrap the code in main in try catch. Both will handle the exception in decent way.

But I want detect this situation in early stage, Is there is any way do that.

Comment: You need checked exceptions.  I can't recall - does C++ have them?  Sounds like the answer is "no".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ does not support Java-style restrictive exception declarations, and cannot do it for a number of reasons. Your compiler can't and won't warn you about exceptions that were not caught. The C++ throw() specifications serve a different purpose (or, arguably, no purpose at all at the moment).

The standard solution is to make sure all exceptions derive from `stdexcept` classes and to catch `std::exception` or `std::runtime_error` at an appropriate place. This normally means a very high-level place, e.g. the controller function that activated an action.

Comment: "_Java-style restrictive exception declarations_" Java exception specification, unlike C++ ES, are actually permissive and unenforced.

Answer (score 2):

C++ (thankfully) does not require functions to advertize what exceptions they might throw. Therefore, in general, any function *may* throw anything. You don't know and your compiler doesn't know.

Therefore, you have to take it upon yourself to track what exceptions get thrown from where, and where they get caught.

Comment: well there are exception specifications but their behavior seems to be very platform dependent and they don't actually limit what you can throw: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfa0edys.aspx

Comment: @PeterT "_they don't actually limit what you can throw_" They do, unless your compiler is badly broken.

Answer (score 0):

> But I want detect this situation in early stage, Is there is any way do that.

If you want to handle errors locally, you should not use exceptions.